# Why am I getting two different outputs from Python and C++ using GDAL?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, coordinate-system, c++

I am trying to gather information from a *.tif file using the GDAL libraries. When I open the *.tif file using both the Python API, and C++ API, I encouter two completely different answers. Here are the two blocks of code, and their terminal outputs:

Python

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import GA_ReadOnly

def main():
    data_set = gdal.Open("file_name.tif", GA_ReadOnly)
    print data_set.GetProjectionRef()
    print 'Driver: ', data_set.GetDriver().LongName

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
PROJCS["unnamed",PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-105],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

Driver:  GeoTIFF

C++

```
#include "gdal_priv.h"

int main() {
  GDALDataset  *poDataset;

  GDALAllRegister();

  poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen("file_name.tif", GA_ReadOnly);

  if(poDataset == NULL)
    return 0;

  if(poDataset->GetProjectionRef() != NULL)
    printf("Projection is `%s'\n", poDataset->GetProjectionRef());

  printf(
    "Driver: %s/%s\n", poDataset->GetDriver()->GetDescription(), 
    poDataset->GetDriver()->GetMetadataItem(GDAL_DMD_LONGNAME));

  return 0;
}
```

Output

Projection is

```
`PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 13N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-105],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32613"]]'
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
```

If it helps in the answer. I used the terminal to install the C libraries, and I am using Anaconda to manage my Python libraries.

Comment: and the result of  `gdalinfo file_name.tif` ?

Comment: @gene:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: file_name.tif
Size is 9500, 8541
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-105],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (479274.000000000000000,4426986.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.00000000000000,-1.00000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Band 1 Block=9500x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray

Comment: I don't think the 2 different outputs are completely different. They seem to be functionally equivalent.

Comment: @JesseCrocker You are right. I should rephrase. The output of the Python code seems to be a subset of the output of the C++ code.

Comment: Make sure GDAL_DATA is properly set for both instances.

Answer (score 1):

If the output from `gdalinfo file_name.tif` is to be believed, it looks like the C++ implementation assumed your datum was WGS84 and filled out the rest of the WKT for you, although there shouldn't be an entry for both `PROJCS` and `GEOGCS`.

It's hard to tell for certain without digging into the gdal source code and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand the logic of the Python version of GDAL. With a raster with the same projection (EPSG:3857)

```
from osgeo import gdal
data_set = gdal.Open("test.tif")
# Getting the Spatial Reference System (returned in Well Known Text(WKT) format)
projInfo = data_set .GetProjection()
projInfo
'PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]'
data_set.GetDriver().LongName
'GeoTIFF'
```

We can also use the osr module to create a spatial reference object

```
from osgeo import osr
Ref = osr.SpatialReference()
Ref.ImportFromWkt(projInfo)
# Proj.4 format
RefProj = Ref.ExportToProj4()
print Ref
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
print RefProj
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs
```